# count the value of nid

Tags: php, count, drupal-7

I want to calculate count for the table field(n_id).I want to count the nid and allow sorting based on count.I have the code for sorting based on nid I want to sort based on nid count as shown in image
[image: Description]

```
$data['link_click_count']['table']['join'] = array(
'node' => array(
  'handler' => 'views_join',
  'left_table' => 'node',
  'left_field' => 'nid',
  'field' => 'nid',
  ),
 );
 $data['link_click_count']['nid'] = array(   //sorting based on nid 
'title' => t('Link Node id'),
'help' => t('Link Node id.'),
'field' => array(
  'handler' => 'views_handler_field_numeric',
  'click sortable' => TRUE,
),
'filter' => array(
  'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_numeric',
),
'sort' => array(
  'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
),
'argument' => array(
  'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_numeric',
),
);
```

Comment: downvoter plz mention reason.It may helps to improve my question

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT COUNT(NID) CNT FROM TABLENAME GROUP BY NID
)Z ORDER BY Z.CNT
```

Please try above code.
Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
SELECT nid, count(1) FROM table GROUP BY nid ORDER BY count(1)
```